# Topology(meaning)

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

When we define Topology we say that a topology on a set(let's say X) is a collection of subsets of X having certain 3 properties. Now, here what do we actually mean by saying "topology on a set". What is the geometrical picture of this topology?

Comment: I'd say about the only "geometric picture" you get is what arises from the topological notions: a topology (or two, depending) defines continuity, convergence of sequences, convergence of nets, compactness, connectedness, the family of fundamental groups at each point, more advanced algebraic-topological notions, etc.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves downvotes with no comments on why. The only issue is that the question seems to assume that if something is defined in math, it probably has a geometric representation. However it is not true that you may geometrically represent all of mathematics, topology included. However, you can intuitively explain concepts, and my favourite for a "topology on a set" is that the topology defines the intuitive 'closeness' of elements in the set to each other. Two elements in an open set means we may say these elements are "close" in some meaning of the word.

Comment: I should add that my "intuitive meaning" of a topology on a set is derived from the analogous structure of open sets in metric spaces, where we can easily see a meaning for the concept of a "neighbourhood" in a topology. If you are unfamiliar with a neighbourhood in a topology, the most general version is that a set $N$ is a neighbourhood of a point $x \in N$ iff there exists an open set $O$ such that $x \in O \subseteq N$.

Comment: A geometric picture won't totally work since that might be taken to imply the presence of a concept of distance and/or spatial structure. Etymologically, one might take "topology on a set" to mean "a study of locations on the set". So every element of a topology can be thought of as a location (a quantum cloud, if you will). The topology (the collection of subsets) can be thought of as a collection of locations. Each element of the parent set is located in many subsets, and is located in any arbitrary union of them and is located in each finite intersection of them.

Comment: In nonstandard topology, infinitesimals are a thing — for any set $X$, the set $X^*$ (created by fiddling with the axiom of choice) is basically $X$ but with "nonstandard elements." $\Bbb R^*$, for example, includes infinitesimals and their reciprocals, infinitely large (_unbounded_) numbers. The monad of $x$, $\mu(x)$, designates an "infinitesimal neighborhood" of $x$; formally, it's the intersection of $N_x^*$ for all neighborhoods $N_x$ of $x$. All topological properties can be restated in terms of monads. The nonstandard definitions of many things are more intuitive than the standard ones.

Comment: I find it useful to know the nonstandard definitions of things as well as the standard definitions. Note that nonstandard topology isn't very well known. An example definition: A function is continuous if $f(\mu(x))\subseteq\mu(f(x))$.

Answer (score 3):

I wish there was a simple answer to your question. A simple enough answer might be worthy of a serious award.

There are two problems. The first is that the intuition of topology involves learning hard theorems. Compactness (an even less intuitive concept) and Connectedness are critical to our intuition about topologies. Separation axioms help us categorize spaces by how friendly they are, but involve tough proofs.  Geometry comes later, almost as an application in the nice settings, like locally Euclidean spaces.

Problem two is that there are some really scary topological spaces. People talk about "closeness" or "nearby" as related to topology, and they're right. But what does that really mean in spaces that badly fail T1, or some other basic structure? It's hard to say. And even harder to visualize. There are tricks, but things like the sorgenfrey plane (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane) are so wildly different than "nicer" structures it makes it generalization quite hard.

Long story short, keep working and thinking about it, and don't be discouraged by lack of clarity at first. As I was said to me, I'll say to you "learn the fundamentals." There is no other way.